# is this sentence correct with the present perfect?

Tags: questions

I'm taking a practice test of the present perfect, I'm confuse with this tense.

It started to snow last night and it still _____.

I just want to know it the answer I gave it, I was correct this was my answer

It started to snow last night and it still hasn't stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It started to snow last night and it still hasn't stopped. (Present Perfect)
Your answer is correct. You could also say: It has been snowing since last night. (Present Perfect Continuous)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that sentence is correct. 
Present perfect can be used to describe an action or situation that started in the past and continues in the present / an action performed during a period that has not yet finished.